# App rejection with Invalid Binary as reason on AppStoreConnect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

I was successfully able to deploy Version 1.6 on AppStore.
But now, in version 1.7, they are showing me **Invalid Binary** error when I submit my app for review. My app is getting rejected but the reason for rejection is not being given by Apple.

Please let me know if you have faced a similar issue and please do guide me on how to solve it.
Please check the images I have attached for clarity.

[Rejection Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nnT3.png)

[Rejection Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFKFL.png)

[Version History](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7Dhe.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can find some clues in your rejection message, please read it carefully.
In App Store Connect, there is a section where you enter privacy information. Some questions asked and you need to answer them according your app's usage of personal data. Please refer to links in your rejection message for more information.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to solve this

**First Way:** Answer the Apple security question in app store, that why your application is using third party libraries. As these libraries gets user's data.
So you have to justify that why your application need to use third party libraries

**Second Way:** You can add privacy policy in login and registration screen. So that user be aware that his/her data might be shared on the app.